# Android: Polling for every 2 sec

Tags: android, json, long-polling

One feature of my application is to retrieve live data (JSON object) every 2 sec and display it  (only while app is in foreground). I am executing an async task for every 2 sec. But this is making the app slow. I have searched for alternative, but i only got C2DM option. I can't use it because of server limitations.
 *Could you please tell me an alternative or effective way for polling?*

Comment: For polling use a `service` instead of a `Async task`

Comment: But wouldn't it be a overhead again to update activity from service ?

Answer (score 0):

One option, if you have control of your server, is that you can switch to something like Comet (long-held http requests) to avoid the necessity of ongoing polling requests.

Comment: But i dont have any control on server.

Comment: So my only suggestion would be to poll again only after you've received the response. If that won't help, try using normal threads and handlers... That's the way I do it and I don't feel any slowness in my app

Comment: I implemented the functionality with handler but if i use handler there is a delay in Updating the UI.

Comment: It could be something else that causing the delay. What device are you testing on? If it's the emulator, note that it's considerably slower than real devices

Answer (score 0):

change the execution of the async task from every two sec to after getting the response for previous update you can initiate it in onpostexecute function... this will make your ui faster
also try using gzip so that the data gets transferred faster do not pool async task

your ui is getting slower as an async task is shot up before the previous one ore ones have completed